# C linkedlist removeLast using pointers

Tags: c, linked-list, function-pointers, singly-linked-list

I am learning how to make linked lists in c and I have come across a problem that I cant figure out how to solve. I am having problems with my removeLast(link * ptr) method for my linked list and I believe it has something to do with my use of pointers but I really don't understand why the program fails to remove the next last element from the list, somehow my list gets destroyed. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// typedef is used to give a data type a new name
typedef struct node * link ;// link is now type struct node pointer

/*
    typedef allows us to say "link ptr"
    instead of "struct node * ptr"
*/

struct node{
    int item ;// this is the data
    link next ;//same as struct node * next, next is a pointer
};

//prints the link
void printAll(link ptr){
    printf("\nPrinting Linked List:\n");
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf(" %d ", (*ptr).item);
        ptr = (*ptr).next;// same as ptr->next
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//adds to the head of the link
// link * ptr so that we may modify the head pointer
void addFirst(link * ptr, int val ){
    link tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));// allocates memory for new node
    tmp->item = val;
    tmp->next = * ptr;
    * ptr = tmp;
}

// removes and returns the last element in the link
// link * ptr so that we may modify the head pointer
link removeLast(link * ptr){

    if(ptr == NULL) return NULL;

    // traverse the link
    link prev = NULL;// prev is pointer
    while((*ptr)->next != NULL){
        prev = *ptr;
        *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
    }

    // if only one node on list
    if(prev == NULL){
        link tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));// allocates memory for new node
        tmp = *ptr;
        *ptr = NULL;
        return tmp;
    }

    // if more than one node
    prev->next = NULL;
    return *ptr;
}

// testing
int main(void) {

    link head = NULL;// same as struct node * head, head is a pointer type

    //populating list
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        addFirst(&head, i);// "&" is needed to pass address of head
    }

    printAll(head);

    while(head != NULL){
        link tmp = removeLast(&head);
        if(tmp != NULL)
            printf(" %d ", tmp->item);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is my output:

```
    Printing Linked List:
     9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
    prev = 9
    prev = 8
    prev = 7
    prev = 6
    prev = 5
    prev = 4
    prev = 3
    prev = 2
     0  0 
    RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 136ms)
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a pointer to `head` to `removeLast()` (parameter `ptr`). In that function you modify `*ptr`.

Since `ptr` points to the memory location where the `head` variable lives, modifying `*ptr` modifies the contents of `head`. Since the contents of `head` get modified by the function call it doesn't refer to the actual head of the list after the function returns.

To avoid this you should use a separate local variable in `removeLast()` to walk over the list and only modify `*ptr` when you really mean to change `head`.

Comment: thank you that solved my problem, thank you so much you where so right about the `*ptr` modifying the `head` pointer. I made a new pointer to traverse the link and it worked than you so much, may GOD bless u with a bunch of kids.